# What is the difference between JOIN ON and JOIN WITH in Doctrine2?

Tags: sql, join, doctrine-orm, dql

What is the difference between JOIN ON and JOIN WITH in Doctrine2?

I couldn't find any relevant info in the manual.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`ON` replaces the original join condition,
`WITH` adds a condition to it.

---

**Example**:

```
[Album] ---OneToMany---> [Track]
```

1. Case One

   **DQL**

   ```
   FROM Album a LEFT JOIN a.Track t WITH t.status = 1
   ```

   **Will translate in SQL**

   ```
   FROM Album a LEFT JOIN Track t ON t.album_id = a.id AND t.status = 1
   ```
2. Case Two

   **DQL**

   ```
   FROM Album a LEFT JOIN a.Track t ON t.status = 1
   ```

   **Will translate in SQL**

   ```
   FROM Album a LEFT JOIN Track t ON t.status = 1
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't really get your point, can you provide me an example?

Comment: Yes, let's say you have an Album table linked with a Track table (one to many)...

In DQL, if you do `FROM Album a LEFT JOIN a.Track t WITH t.status = 1`, it's the equivalent of SQL `FROM Album a LEFT JOIN Track t ON t.album_id = a.id AND t.status = 1`

But if you do `FROM Album a LEFT JOIN a.Track t ON t.status = 1`, it will be the equivalent of SQL `FROM Album a LEFT JOIN Track t ON t.status = 1`, thus replacing the relation condition (`t.album_id = a.id`). 

Hope I'm clear !

Comment: I'm not editing the answer because I'm not 100% sure I got it, but I reckon that you use `Join::ON` to set your own join conditions for this query and you use `Join::WITH` to use the conditions set in the entity model as starting point and merely add additional clauses. And, at least for me, `Join::ON` refuses to work in Symfony no matter what.