# How to use Doctrine 2 DQL ON to override default JOIN condition

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm-postgres

For starters, it is NOT a duplicate of [Doctrine 2 JOIN ON error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939148/doctrine-2-join-on-error). I am indeed getting `Expected end of string, got 'ON'` but using `WITH` won't solve my case.

The problem there is similar but different from mine. I don't need to **add** a condition to my `JOIN`, I need to **substitute** the default condition with a different one.

Let's say, we have 2 hypthetical tables: `album` and `artist`, with an `artist_id` FK pointing from `album` to `artist`. In my case, I **don't** want to join artists with their albums. I want to list artists joined with unrelated albums using some arbitrary condition. So each artist will be joined with the exact same small set of albums. Believe me, in my case it does make sense - I don't want to describe it fully because it is too complex and out of the scope of my question.

```
SELECT * FROM artist
  LEFT JOIN album ON album.some_unrelated_property = 'foo'
```

The example above is raw SQL (I'm using PostgreSQL) and works perfectly fine in this form.

In my code I'm using query builder (hard to avoid it, because my query is way more complex and built step by step by a series of functions). The line that causes an error is this:

```
$qb->leftJoin('artist.albums', 'aa', Join::ON, 'aa.someUnrelatedProperty = "foo"');
```

In Doctrine I'm getting the dreaded `Expected end of string, got 'ON'`. When I use `WITH` instead of `ON` it works, but as expected, it appends the standard join condition by `artist_id` which I do not want.

What's even more confusing for me, in this post: [What is the difference between JOIN ON and JOIN WITH in Doctrine2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137908/what-is-the-difference-between-join-on-and-join-with-in-doctrine2) which explains a difference between `ON` and `WITH` in DQL, somebody uses an example equivalent to mine as a correct use of `ON` in DQL:

> Case Two
>
> DQL
>
> `FROM Album a LEFT JOIN a.Track t ON t.status = 1`
>
> Will translate in SQL
>
> `FROM Album a LEFT JOIN Track t ON t.status = 1`

What am I missing here? Is it possible to achieve what I want at all, using DQL? If not, what the hell is the reason for `ON` to exist in DQL when there's also `WITH` which works in more standard cases?

Comment: note the question you have linked is about Doctrine 1, not Doctrine 2. Also note [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26101872/what-is-the-difference-between-with-and-on-in-doctrine-join-condition-type/26103979)